# Error Launching Idea. Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Whenever I open IntelliJ IDEA i get this error:

[image]

but I have that defined and I don't know why it wont work:

[image]

Any help accepted.

Comment: After define JAVA_HOME did you try to restart the IDE?

Comment: I had this issue when trying to start PHPStorm via the command line (add the phpstorm bin folder to your path, and you should be able to do eg `phpstorm.exe .` - adding the path to the jdk PHPStorm comes bundled with as  `JAVA_HOME` (`setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.1\jre64"`) doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Plz follow this solution it's perfect work for me [ Follow this Steps ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155444/android-studio-electric-eel-update-failure/75156452#75156452)

Answer (score 36):

It could be problem with 32 and 64 version. Maybe you trying to launch 32-bit shortcut on your Desktop. Try to launch 64 version (idea64.exe) inside IDEA folder. This worked for me.

Comment: This fixed my issue. If you're launching using the "start menu" search for "goland" in windows it tries to locate the x86 version of the JDK even if you have the x64 version installed.

Comment: It seems recent versions like 2019.2 only have 64 bit version to be downloaded now.

Comment: Similarly for "goland" run "**goland64 .**" from the command line.

Comment: I've got this error trying to open Maven project using command: `idea pom.xml` . But since I have no x86 JDK installed in my system this doesn't work. So one should use `idea64 pom.xml` with x64 JDK.

Answer (score 29):

Change the following value from your `Path` system variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

to:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Also make sure there are no any other references to Java folders in the `Path` variable.

Comment: This worked, and I wonder why this persists as a problem until 2019...Pycharm?

Comment: If you're doing it in 2019 try my answer below instead, no need to fiddle with the Path.

Answer (score 7):

To fix I didn't need to touch my environment variables.

I fixed that issue by installing/re-installing the latest PHPStorm version choosing the option to keep old settings, logging out from Windows and logging back in.

Comment: Installing/re-installing the latest version of what? The jetbrain program?

Comment: Yes reinstalling phpstorm altogether

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by:

1. Setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the location of the JDK I wanted to use e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171`
2. Replacing any paths referring to Java e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll` in `Path` with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` as suggested by [DimaSan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40206980/6221831)
3. Removing the following from the **System variables** path `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

The last step was crucial for me, this was overriding `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually i had installed the Android Studio canary version, and created a short cut of 32-bit on 64-bit windows operating system,

```
resolved by starting 64-bit version of Android Studio
```

Comment: I had to run Android Studio as administrator on Windows10. Strange because I was able to run without doing this yesterday and upto an hour ago.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing of the other solutions work for me on IntelliJ 2019.2 which starts to use JDK 11 on boot, so I have to resolve it on my own.

Open C:\Users\.IdeaIC2019.2\config\idea64.exe.jdk and edit it to be:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

Restart IDE.

As documented on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html

Note: the path on your machine may be different.

Comment: Plus, why should I switch back to use JDK 1.8 is because one of my addin/plugin to extend project templates relies on JDK 1.8 and breaks for JDK 11.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this error appeared after signing in to Microsoft account (I use Windows 10). When I logged out, the error dissapeared.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do nothing buddy.
Just use 32 bit version of application or install 64 bit JDK. You installed 32 bit JDK and you are trying to access 64 bit version of that application.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem and in my case, just right click and "Run as administrator", everything works fine.

P.S. I am using Windows 10 in our company's domain.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by running Android studio as admin.

Just Check on that path if the `jvm.dll` is present just run Android studio as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue after updating android studio version **electric eel**. it's show error like this.
[image]

After many try I found this solution. you can follow this steps.

Step 1 : You can visit this site [Official Oracle Java SE Development Kit Site](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/downloads/) and download particular JDK kit for your pc configuration. I am suggest to download this JDK version [Java SE Development Kit 18.0.2.1](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk18-archive-downloads.html) and after download you can install in your computer.

Step 2 : After Successfully installed you can go

**Stat**--> **Search**--> **Edit Environment Variable** -->
You can follow this image

1.[image]

[image]

Step 3:
Now You can Add **JAVA_HOME:** *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1* (install version in your pc) Like this
[image]

and also add **PATH** : *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin* (install version in your pc) Like this
[image]

**Note** : You can only add user variable not system variable.

**Step 4 : Last step but main after follow these steps you can restart your pc.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing Intellij Idea on a 32 bit System - the JDK will not come within the bundle.

To fix this issue follow the steps below :

1.Uninstall the installed Intellij IDEA

2.Download and install JDK SE 8 from this link :
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html

3.Install Intellij IDEA

Viola !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - My solution was slightly different.

[I needed to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14632)

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to start PHPStorm via the command line (add the phpstorm bin folder to your path, and you should be able to do eg `phpstorm.exe .`) - my local installed worked fine.

see also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html:

> Add the path to the PhpStorm  `bin` folder to the **Path** environment variable (for example, `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm\bin`). After you configured the **Path** environment variable, you can run the PhpStorm commands.

adding the path to the jdk PHPStorm comes bundled with as  `JAVA_HOME` (`setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.1\jre64"`) doesn't solve the issue as the default `phpstorm.exe` tries to find a 32-bit jdk

I needed to specifically use the 64-bit phpstorm application
**`phpstorm64.exe .`**

Answer (score 0):

Can be several reasons:

1). Check that your jdk-byte architecture is the same as your os-byte. So, 32-nit architecture needs 32-bit jdk, 64 bit architecture needs 64 bit jdk.

2). If you're running a 64-bit architecture, use (idea64.exe, phpstorm64.exe, etc.). On the 32-bit architecture use (idea.exe, phpstorm.exe, etc), to launch intelli-j products from the command line or terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (JDK 1.8.0_212), but none of the suggested solution worked. I then installed a newer JDK (1.8.0_261) and the problem was solved (obviously, I had to update the JAVA_HOME too).