# Error launching IDEA: Failed to load JVM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, system-variable

I recently installed IntelliJ IDEA 2018. However, when I tried to run IntelliJ, I received the following error message:

Error loading IDEA:
[image: Error loading IDEA]

I looked up my system environment variables which I have posted below:

System Variables:
[image: System Variables]

I checked which version of Java I have on the command prompt:

Java Version | Command Prompt:
[image: Java Version | Command Prompt]

I checked my program files:

Program Files | JDK 9:
[image: Program Files | JDK 9]

I also checked my Program Files (x86):

Program Files (x86) | JRE 1.8:
[image: Program Files (x86) | JRE 1.8]

Comment: Its always more readable to type in or paste them as image instead of links

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Launching Idea. Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\_112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204189/error-launching-idea-failed-to-load-jvm-dll-c-program-files-java-jdk1-8-0-112)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I apologize that my post isn't more readable. I hope you can view my images. I did see that post, however, when I attempted to use the solution provided (edit the Path within system variables to reference %JAVA_HOME%\bin, my problem persisted. Also, my error message is slightly different from the one posted. My error message references jetbrains and the jre that was installed with Intellij

Comment: *Not currently allowed to embed images in posts yet, need to have links instead :/

Comment: please post the contents of `%PATH%` here as text (you may blacken personal data though, if you want to) - the screenshot doesn't show the full PATH

Answer (score 3):

I've had an issue in the past where the oracle jdk was given priority over the jdk I wanted to use and eclipse wouldn't load because of it.  While this is not exactly the same issue it seems similar in nature since I see you have a listing for Oracle/java/javapath in your Path environment variable.

I can see in your path that oracle is listed first.

Try listing %JAVA_HOME%/bin; as the first entry inside your Path variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although listing listing %JAVA_HOME%/bin; as the first entry inside your Path variable didn't work for me, listing it last did the job!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for your help. Listing %JAVA_HOME%/bin; as the last entry inside my Path variable resolved my issue.

[IntelliJ Now Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFGsT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below path from your local machine

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\server\jvm.dill

And Set the Environment Variables

> Set the %JAVA_HOME%\bin

I faced same issue and resolved from 
http://commandstech.com/intellij-idea-failed-to-load-jvm-dll/

Answer (score 0):

I "resolved" it by deleting the jvm.dll file in C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.4\jbr\bin\server.
Then it started looking up the JAVA_HOME variable and the program launched.