# Intelli IDEA didn't start 32bit installed jvm.dll

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

my Intelli IDEA didn't start after reinstallation - it I click idea64.exe nothing happens -

if I click idea.exe following window appears - what is wrong - any help?

[image]

Edit: I've moved the java folder to Program Files (x86) Folder

Afterwards following appears

[image]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll = JavaHome

%JAVA_HOME%\bin = Path ... didn't see the point

maybe to start 32 - when I click idea64 nothing happens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Launching Idea. Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\_112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204189/error-launching-idea-failed-to-load-jvm-dll-c-program-files-java-jdk1-8-0-112)

Comment: no it doesn't help :(